# How can Export Categories with product on Magento 2

Tags: magento2, importexport

How can Export Categories with product on  Magento 2

Magento 2 admin panel only product export/import but categories sequence problem, product not import , so i want to export all categories with product

Comment: There is option in administration panel

Comment: There only product export/import but categories sequence problem , so i want to export all categories  with product

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default categories export option is not available with magento 2.

But you can do a trick like **export a product with specific categories id.**

**go to system -> export -> products -> then in the entity attribute selection**

**select categories and add categories_id over there and then do export**

**it will export specific categories products.**

**Or else second thing you can use extension for that**

**here is the extensions link -**

1) https://firebearstudio.com/blog/commerce-extensions-bulk-categories-import-export-magento-2.html

2) https://www.commerceextensions.com/bulk-categories-import-export-csv-xml-magento-2.html

Comment: I do this after edit categories field exported product csv as my new site category structure ( Ex. Default Category,Default Category/Men )

Comment: I open the import page many times, never noticed the "Category" filtering option. It works fine. Thanks.

Comment: @MJoraid - Glad to know that it works for you ! happy to help and keep helping :)